# How to update array of entity in React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a following state:

```
  const [addingItems, setAddingItems] = useState({
     entityOne: [],
     entityTwo: [],
  });
```

I need to create function which adds values for each entity. I tried something like this:

```
const addEntityOne = (item) => {
    setAddingItems({ ...addingItems, entityOne: [...addingItems.entityOne, item] });
  };
```

or this:

```
  const addEntityOne = (id) => {
    const state = { ...addingItems };
    state. entityOne.push(id);
    setAddingItems(state);
  };
```

and different similar approaches.
But always after update I have array of arrays:

```
entityOne: Array(2)
0: ["5fcc15d567184993fdfd8a25"]
1: (2) [Array(1), "5fcc15d567184993fdfd8a27"]
length: 2
```

What is my problem and how to crate right function?

Comment: Well, is `item` or `id` an array in either of your examples?

Comment: items :) I tried to make it abstract, but forgot to replace in second sample

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. in your first definition of `addEntityOne` you set it equal to a function that takes a parameter `item`, is it possible that whatever calls `addEntityOne` is actually passing an array?

Comment: What @SamGomena said has to be the case, because his first implementation works just fine, see my codesandbox below.

Answer (score 1):

Your first first solution works just fine, see this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-sound-9tq19?file=/src/App.js) with a minimal example.

As one of the comments suggest, it's probably how you are calling `addEntityOne`, where `item` is already an array.

Your 2nd approach is incorrect, as you are directly manipulating `state` which should never be done. If you need to mutate data in the state, always create a deep clone before doing so.

Comment: You are right. I had wrong input variable. Thank you to help me find this fact :)

Comment: Consider accepting this answer if I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cerf-j47w8?file=/src/App.js:0-1276).

Your first approach works fine.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [entityInput, setEntityInput] = useState("");
  const [entityType, setEntityType] = useState("entityOne");
  const [addingItems, setAddingItems] = useState({
    entityOne: [1, 2, 3],
    entityTwo: [4, 5]
  });

  function changeEntityContent() {
    setAddingItems((state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        [entityType]: [...state[entityType], entityInput]
      };
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(e) => setEntityInput(e.target.value)} />
      <label htmlFor="entity">Choose entity</label>
      <select
        name="entity"
        id="entity"
        onChange={(e) => setEntityType(e.target.value)}
      >
        <option value="entityOne">Entity One</option>
        <option value="entityTwo">Entity Two</option>
      </select>
      <button onClick={changeEntityContent}> add </button>

      <h2> Entity One </h2>
      <ul>
        {addingItems.entityOne.map((eo) => {
          return <li key={Math.random()}> {eo} </li>;
        })}
      </ul>

      <h2> Entity Two </h2>
      <ul>
        {addingItems.entityTwo.map((eo) => {
          return <li key={Math.random()}> {eo} </li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```